# image rotation going to wide off of my screen how to keep static or shorten width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Hello guys I was wondering if anyone has a quick fix to my image rotating way to far off my screen and causes my app to have scroll bars and not appealing to the eye maybe have the image just spinning in place to make my formatting issues easier

here is my code
  JS

```
<head>
    <script>
    var looper;
    var degrees = 0;
    function rotateAnimation(el,speed){
        var elem = document.getElementById(el);
        if(navigator.userAgent.match("Chrome")){
            elem.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
        } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("Firefox")){
            elem.style.MozTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
        } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("MSIE")){
            elem.style.msTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
        } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("Opera")){
            elem.style.OTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
        } else {
            elem.style.transform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
        }
        looper = setTimeout('rotateAnimation(\''+el+'\','+speed+')',speed);
        degrees++;
        if(degrees > 359){
            degrees = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
    }
    </script>

</head>
```

HTML

```
<body>


<div data-role="page" id="pageone">


<img id="img1" src="http://s8.postimg.org/h719p5x85/transimage.png" alt="cog1">
<script>rotateAnimation("img1",15);</script>
</body>
```

Comment: anyone? can help me ?

Comment: Set your `transform-origin` to the center of your image and then do the rotation. Even with this adjustment the corners of your image will rotate beyond their original bounding box. BTW, your `canvas` tag seems irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

As markE said set the transform-origin to the center of the image, so something like this:

```
elem.style.transform-origin = "50% 50%";
elem.style.transform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
```

You can use -ms- and -webkit- for this in your code too for cross compatability.

Slightly unrelated, I suggest using:

```
degrees = degrees%360;
```

instead of your if statement where you wrap from 359 to 1 degrees.
This is because it will work in more general situations, so is less likely to break. For example if you changed the amount of degrees no by +1 but by +10 or -10 it would still wrap correctly between 0 and 360.